# typescript throws syntax errors on react.d.ts definition file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use react with typescript with reactjs and right now typescript is throwing syntax errors on the react.d.ts file I got from github:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/react

The errors are basically like this.

```
file_path/react.d.ts(6,9):
>> error TS1005: ';' expected.
file_path/react.d.ts(6,19):
>> error TS1005: ';' expected.
file_path/react.d.ts(6,27):
>> error TS1005: ';' expected.
file_path/react.d.ts(11,51):
>> error TS1003: Identifier expected.
file_path/react.d.ts(13,5):
>> error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'statement' expected.
```

I upgraded my version to typescript to the latest 1.6.2 as others have suggested could be the problem, but still it exists.

This is a large ongoing project that has been using typescript the whole time, its just the react.d.ts file it doesnt like.

What are some other things I can try so typescript will accept the definition file?

Answer (score 0):

> I upgraded my version to typescript to the latest 1.6.2 as others have suggested could be the problem, but still it exists.

I realize you've said this, but it is not true. The only plausible reason you would get this error is because you're using an older version of the compiler. Run `tsc --v` and figure out why your compiler upgrade didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is the response from your command: message TS6029: Version 1.6.2. My webapp is using grunt and has grunt-typescript node module version 2.8.3. Could this be the cause of my problem? Not sure the difference between these two modules. I also installed typscript globally so it would have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the problem with my build issue. Turns out it was the grunt-typescript node module. That module was out of date which was using an old version typescript inside it.

upgraded grunt-typescript to 0.8 (current version) and now current version of typescript is being used.